# Codeigniter dynamic viewloader

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, dynamic

I have been working on a dynamic viewloader and I ran into some problems.
Eventhough it's working fine when I get an "edit" I can't seem to fix the code in a nice way once I get to an add.

The current viewLoader looks as follow: http://pastebin.com/e9piMJBW

The problem I'm getting is that at line 45:

```
 $values['data'] = $this->DoQuery($url[(count($url) - 3)], $url[(count($url) - 2)], $url[(count($url) - 1)]);
```

I'm always expecting my url to be as : domain.com/something/users/edit/55.

Where the last 3 segments of my URL would define what to do.

users => Table

Edit => function and

55 would be the ID of the user.

I use this for my admin panel so it will automaticly get / insert data depending on the URL and $_POST values.

My question is that once I have an add this senario will be different. The URL will look as follow:

domain.com/something/users/add

I will no longer have all 3 values (as expected with edit / delete)

Comment: I'm not sure why you doing that. Why you don't use the "normal" routing system? You can achieve the same, with less code.

Comment: This is not a routing system, this is some automatic system that will detect which header , page and footer to load. In case of an edit / delete it will automaticly execute some functions, it's basicly some extension for the
    $this->load->view();

Comment: What exactly you want ?

Comment: Format url or solve issue on line 45 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem at line 45 could be solved as follows :

```
 function generateUrl(){
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $url = explode("/", $this->uri->uri_string());
    $values = array();

    if (count($url) == 5 ) {// Edit of Delete
      $values['data'] = $this->DoQuery($url[(count($url) - 3)], $url[(count($url) - 2)], $url[(count($url) - 1)]);
    }
    else {  //Add
      $values['data'] = $this->DoQuery($url]count($url)-2)],$url[(count($url) -1)]);
   }
    ......
```

Comment: I indeed had this already and is working just fine. I'm only a little sad that this looks like the only way of fixing the problem because I was trying to avoid the if() statement